# What tasmota commands (web console) will turn on an indicator LED that I suspect is at gpio3?

Tags: tasmota

I've just used tuya-convert to flash a Soundance C198 powerstrip. This is my first time doing anything like that, and I'm a little lost. The web interface gives me a list of gpios 0-10, and 12-17. These can be configured as LEDs 1-4 (either with an led or led_i setting).

At some point, I've set all of those to LED, and through the console I've ran the `LedPower1 1` and `LedPower 1` commands. These do not seem to produce any errors, but they also don't turn on any LEDs (2 on the device).

Am I supposed to be using some other command to turn these on? Can I turn on more than one gpio at a time (so I can do a binary search)?

The list of tasmota supported devices does not include this device, nor goes Google turn up much other than an Amazon UK page to buy more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to stem from using the *Configure Template* menu option in Tasmota. While it provides a nice user interface that displays all of the options, clicking save after making changes doesn't always result in those changes taking effect (either immediately or sometimes at all).

It is much better to use the *Configure Other* menu option, and input the template manually, as a json string:

```
{"NAME":"ID Relays","GPIO":[0,0,0,0,224,225,0,0,226,227,228,229,230,0],"FLAG":0,"BASE":18}
```

Everything should be put in as a relay at first (because only relays will have the clickable buttons when the page reloads). Saving from the *Configure Other* page does seem to always activate the changes, though some configurations seem to be screwy enough that not much will work.

The first json string to use should be:

```
{"NAME":"ID Relays","GPIO":[224,225,226,227,228,229,0,0,230,231,0,0,0,0],"FLAG":0,"BASE":18}
```

Toggle all 8 of the buttons, and see what happens. At least for my device, an LED will toggle as if a relay (but if you set it for the code number for LEDs, you get no button to test/debug with, so wait to do that for now).

Some of your buttons will show as "off" or 0, when the device is on, and vice versa. These will have to be configured as relay_i, led_i, etc (the _i is for "inverted). You can wait to do that for now. When you find a device, mark down which one it corresponds to.

The 7th and 8th positions should be left as zero, as well as the last. So if you have to hunt for more devices, then use this json string next:

```
{"NAME":"ID Relays","GPIO":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,224,225,226,0],"FLAG":0,"BASE":18}
```

Once saved and the page reloads, test all 3 buttons as before. Mark down which are inverted, what device they activate.

When you have all the devices identified, use the *Configure Template* page to adjust each to inverted, or to LEDs, or whatever. All relays have to be sequential, so that the top one is 1, the next (no matter how many gpios are skipped) is 2, and so on. Same for LEDs. Inverted relays and LEDs still share the same sequence. Once saved, it might be necessary to go into *Configure Other* and save it there to activate it.

For this level of device discovery, console commands seem unnecessary. Also, Tasmota seems to want to take over the first LED, such that you may not get to use it with console commands anyway... seems to automatically make it into a power status indicator.

In summary:

1. Only relays get virtual buttons on the main page/menu.
2. The *Configure Template* page doesn't always activate changes you make.
3. Tasmota is finicky about making similar devices sequential.